# How to consume 3rd party RESTapi response into database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest

In my Laravel project I am making calls to a 3rd party api and am trying to consume some of the data from the json response into my database.

**My function**

```
public function addPlaid(Request $request) // adds a plaid user
{
  $username = $request->input('bank_username');
  $password = $request->input('bank_password');
  $pin = $request->input('pin'); // set null
  $type = $request->input('type');
  $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser($username, $password, $pin, $type);

  return $authUser;
}
```

**My response**

```
{
    "type": "device",
    "mfa": {
        "message": "Code sent to t...t@plaid.com"
    },
    "access_token": "test_chase"
}
```

Here I wanna save the "access_token" value from the JSON response into my `users` table under the `plaid_access_token` column. I've gone on to alter my function to try and do so.

```
public function addPlaid(Request $request) // adds a plaid user
{
  $username = $request->input('bank_username');
  $password = $request->input('bank_password');
  $pin = $request->input('pin'); // set null
  $type = $request->input('type');
  $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser($username, $password, $pin, $type);
  $authUserData = json_decode($authUser['access_token']);
  User::where('user_id', '=', 51)->update(['access_token' => $authUser->access_token]);
  return $authUser;
}
```

but now I am getting an error `Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object`
I am trying to figure out if I am taking the wrong approach with saving it with this line of code `User::where('user_id', '=', 51)->update(['plaid_access_token' => $authUser->access_token]);`

*Note: I'm using user 51 so I know where it saves.*

Comment: If `$authUser` is json, do you need to `json_decode()` before accessing it's properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see it `$authUser` is a JSON string, so you need to decode it before accessing the content (using `json_decode()`)...

```
  $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser($username, $password, $pin, $type);
  $authUserData = json_decode($authUser);
  User::where('user_id', '=', 51)->update(['plaid_access_token' => $authUserData->access_token]);
```

If instead the data is an array, you need to use array notation rather than object notation - `$authUser['access_token']`...

```
  $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser($username, $password, $pin, $type);
  User::where('user_id', '=', 51)->update(['plaid_access_token' => $authUser['access_token']]);
```

Comment: I get an error saying ``json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in``

Comment: OK - try the updated answer - using `$authUser['access_token']`

Comment: I updated the question. im still getting the same error

Comment: Please see the updated answer, you don't need to do the `json_decode()` just update the line `User::where(...`

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
public function addPlaid(Request $request) // adds a plaid user
{
  $username = $request->input('bank_username');
  $password = $request->input('bank_password');
  $pin = $request->input('pin'); // set null
  $type = $request->input('type');
  $authUser = Plaid::addAuthUser($username, $password, $pin, $type);
  if($authUser){
       User::where('user_id', '=', 51)->update(['plaid_access_token' => $authUser["access_token"]);
  }
  return $authUser;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation of why they should try your answer would improve the quality of this answer.